# How to combine subfigures into one

Tags: minipage

My captions display all my figures separately. I'd like it all to be a part of one figure. Here is the code (which is copied verbatim from another answer, although I did spend a fair amount of time to resolve this issue myself) -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment1.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:env}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment2.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:galaxy}
\endminipage\hfill
% <-- GET RID OF PARAGRAPH BREAK
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment3.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\endminipage\hfill% <--PROBABLY WANT AN \hfill
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment4.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\endminipage
\caption{Stuff}
\label{Environment_2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of Figure 1,2,3 and 4, I'd just like the captions a,b,c and d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `subcaption` package and `subfigure` instead of `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment1.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:env}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment2.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:galaxy}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment3.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment4.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Stuff}
\label{Environment_2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is shorter with `floatrow` (which cooperates with `caption` and `subcaption`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox{\begin{subfloatrow}[4]
  \centering
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Environment1.png}}
 {\caption{} \label{fig:env}}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Environment2.png}}
  {\caption{} \label{fig:galaxy}}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Environment3.png}}
{\caption{}\label{}}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Environment4.png}}
{\caption{}\label{sfig}}
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Stuff}\label{Environment_2}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]